# gather_ does not work. Shouldn't quoting and ~ing have the same effect in standard evaluation mode?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

#### I have issues getting tidyr's gather to work in it's standard evaluation version gather_ :

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(lazyeval)

df = data.frame(varName=c(1,2))
```

gather works:

```
df %>% gather(variable,value,varName)
```

but I'd like to be able to take the name varName from a variable in standard evaluation mode, and can't seem to get it right:

```
name='varName'
df %>% gather_("variable","value",interp(~v,v=name))
Error in match(x, y, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

I'm also confused by the following.

This works as expected:

```
df %>% gather_("variable","value","varName")
```

The next line should be equivalent to last line (from my understanding of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html ), but doesn't work:

```
df %>% gather_(~variable,~value,~varName)
Error in match(x, y, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your bigger question, but `gather_(df, "variable", "value", name)` seems to work for this example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source of `tidyr:::gather_.data.frame`, you can see that it is just a wrapper for `reshape2::melt`. As such, it only works for `character` or `numeric` arguments. Acutally the following (which I would consider a bug) works:

```
df %>% gather_("variable", "value", 1)
```

As far as I can tell the `nse` vignette only refers to `dplyr` and not to `tidyr`.

Comment: I'm also have difficulty with this. When using `gather_("variable", "value", 1)` things are fine, but when specifying columns to 'keep' I can't find anyway of parsing them as text:  `gather_("variable", "value", "-keepme")` gives: `object '-keepme' not found`. Doing this with normal gather(...) works fine. Am i missing something? (happy to kick off a new question if that helps)

Comment: @pluke Did you ever figure out how to do: `gather_("variable", "value", "-keepme")`? I cannot seem to find an alternative that works.

Comment: Ah! @LmW's solution of `data %>% gather_("variable", "value", setdiff(names(.), "keepme"))` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been answered, the following code could be used for defining keys and values for gathering purposes more generally in a function, using a vector of inputs for key and value:

```
    data <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10))
    Key <- "ColId"
    Value <- "ColValue"

    data %>% gather(key = KeyTmp, value = ValTmp) %>% 
    rename_(.dots = setNames("KeyTmp", Key) ) %>% 
    rename_(.dots = setNames("ValTmp", Value) )
```

Comment: Actually it is possible to simply do this: `data %>% gather_(key=Key, value=Value, names(.))`

Comment: That works very well for this example, but can it be simply done when you have another column, say:    data <- cbind(Col = c(rep("X",5), rep("Y",5)), data). Now data %>% gather_(key=Key, value=Value, names(.), -Col) does not work? Solution?

Comment: How about this: `data %>% gather_(key=Key, value=Value, setdiff(names(.), 'Col'))` ?

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid "+1" comments, but LmW's comment here really helped me. +1!